# AppVeyor with Devexpress in C#

Tags: appveyor

i'm trying to setup appveyor with my .net project which is using devepxress the 3rd party library. unfortunately, i got this error message when i click build button.

```
Properties\licenses.licx(1): error LC0003: Unable to resolve type 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.ChartControl, DevExpress.XtraCharts.v16.1.UI, Version=16.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' [C:\projects\pda-2000\MotionFake\MotionFake\MotionRealFake.csproj]
Command exited with code 1
```

I guess this is caused from no existence of devexpress dll file. how can i add/upload theses dll files to appveyor?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: no. i gave up..

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is nuget package. If yes, please run `nuget restore` at `install` or `before_build` stage.

Comment: no it's not nuget package, https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/

Comment: In this case you need to investigate can you install this software in unattended way with some script and add this script to 'install' stage of AppVeyor build. Here https://gist.github.com/IlyaFinkelshteyn/68d62223f51652289ab57af4cbcdcdc7#file-installvs2010_shell-ps1-L8 one of unattended installation examples.